# Why can't I compile my java file on cygwin, when it needs classes from a jar?

Tags: java, jar, cygwin, classpath, javac

I'm trying to compile my class along with a provided .jar file which contains classes that my class will use.

This is what I've been trying:

```
javac -classpath .:WordSearch.jar WordSearchSolver.java
```

And this is the response:

```
WordSearchSolver.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PuzzleWord
location: class WordSearchSolver
    public ArrayList<PuzzleWord> findwords()
                 ^
WordSearchSolver.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PuzzleWord
location: class WordSearchSolver
    return new ArrayList<PuzzleWord>();
                         ^
```

2 errors

This is my class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordSearchSolver
{
    public WordSearchSolver(int size, char[][] puzzleboard, ArrayList<String> words)
    {

    }

    public ArrayList<PuzzleWord> findwords()
    {
        return new ArrayList<PuzzleWord>();
    }
}
```

WordSearch.jar contains:

```
PuzzleUI.class
PuzzleWord$Directions.class
PuzzleWord.class
Natural.class
```

(WordSearchSolver.java and Wordsearch.jar are in the same directory)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a combination of semicolons and quotation marks.

```
javac -classpath ".;WordSearch.jar" WordSearchSolver.java
```

Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

Although you're on Cygwin, I'm guessing that your path separator should be a semicolon, since the Java compiler/JVM will be running in a Windows environment.

```
javac -cp .\;WordSearch.jar ...
```

Note that the semicolon must be *escaped* to prevent interpretation by the Cygwin shell (thanks to bkail below)

Comment: I get even stranger errors involving bash when I use semicolons.

Comment: You must quote the semicolon to avoid it being interpreted by Cygwin.  For example, javac -cp .\;WordSearch.jar or javac -cp ".;WordSearch.jar"

Answer (score 1):

You aren't importing any of the classes from your `WordSearch.jar` in your `WordSearchSolver` class.  You need import statements at the top of this class including their package.

Comment: They're in the same package. They don't require importing